# How base string function use in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column named Batch No with some specific data like this

```
TEST1234 - 2022-02-15
100 - 2022-02-15
RO-001 - 2022-02-08
3232 - 2022-02-01
N/A
N/A
MJNK44 - 2021-04-24
MJNK44 - 2021-04-24
N/A
N/A
N/A
564235 - 2021-03-18
```

I want 3232 value in a separate column and 2022-02-01 value in other column how can I do that ?

Comment: Splitting strings is THE MOST COMMON question on SO. Search a little to find examples that are appropriate for your version of sql server.

Comment: See: [String Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). CHARINDEX, LEFT and SUBSTRING are your friends.

Comment: You would use SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, 1,CHARINDEX(‘ - ‘, yourcolumn)…  for the first half, SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, CHARINDEX(‘ - ‘, yourcolumn)+3,8000) to get the second string. You would filter for records <> ‘N/A’) or use a CASE statement to treat those rows differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This is how I solved this ,
case when CHARINDEX(' - ',d.BatchNo)=0 then d.BatchNo
else SUBSTRING(d.BatchNo, 0,CHARINDEX (' - ',d.BatchNo))
end as RoNO,case when CHARINDEX(' - ',d.BatchNo)=0 then d.BatchNo
else SUBSTRING(d.BatchNo, CHARINDEX (' - ',d.BatchNo)+2,20) end as RoDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the position of the dash with `CHARINDEX` or `PATINDEX`.
And use that position to get the substring.

And since the date is always the last 10 characters, just use  `RIGHT` to get it.

```
SELECT *
, NULLIF(SUBSTRING(BatchNo, 0, CHARINDEX(' -', Batchno)),'') as BatchName
, TRY_CONVERT(DATE, RIGHT(BatchNo,10)) as BatchDate
FROM Your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, have used one of the rows for testing, replace *t* with your table name, and remove the *WITH* line.

```
WITH t as (select 'TEST1234 - 2022-02-15' as val)
select t.*,
       LEFT(val, charindex('-', val) - 1), RIGHT(val, LEN(val) - charindex('-', val))
from t;
```